ConnectX-3 Pro (HP 546SFP+) and Supermicro X11SSL/X11SSM RAM Issue
I just stumbled across an unexpected problem when upgrading network cards on a few of my servers: When I put one of my HP 546SFP+ cards (HP branded Mellanox ConnectX-3 PRO dual SFP+ Port 10GbE) into one of my servers equipped with Supermicro X11SSL-F or X11SSM-F mainboards, they refuse to boot up with beep code indicating "No RAM error", if - AND ONLY IF - they are equipped with more than 32 GB of RAM. I tested with three different Cards obtained from different sources on a total of four servers (two each with X11SSL-F and X11SSM-F mainboards, respectively). The servers are running great for a number of years already with a variety of 16GB ECC DIMMs (Samsung, Micron, Kingston). All servers are filled to maximum RAM capacity, that is, four DIMMs of 16GB each. Once RAM capacity is reduced to 32 GB (two DIMMs populated, don't have ower capacity DIMMS available to check whether it's the numer of DIMMs or the total capacity triggering boot failure), or the Network card taken out, they start up just fine. On other Mainboards (Supermicro X10SSL or X10SSH, 32GB RAM maxmimum), the problem does not show up. Any ideas?
